# Matching student names from this school year to names from last school year

Tags: excel

Sheet 1 contains a list from last school year of student names in column A and social security numbers in column B. Sheet 2 contains a list from this school year of student names but Sheet 2 doesn't include social security numbers. I'd like to create a new list that contains current student names and social security numbers of names on sheet 2 that match names on sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names are unique (quite a strong assumption), and assuming that you have these following tables:

> Sheet 1
>
> ```
> A      B
> ```
>
> 1 | Name | SSN |
>
> 2 | X    | x   |
>
> 3 | Z    | z   |
>
> Sheet 2
>
> A      B
>
> 1 | Name | SSN |
>
> 2 | X    | ?   |

You can do the following:

In Sheet 2, in Cell B2, paste =vlookup(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,false)
Then pull this function down the column